# Regular expression in mysql which start with 1

Tags: mysql, regex

Hello i need query for select all records from database containig &var separted by semicolons.
where &var is any number bellow which start with 1, like 123,166,1444
my varchar column look like this "123;166;234;1444"
the column may look and like this 233;166;12, which also containg numbers which start with 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_name where column_name like '1%' or column_name like '%;1%'
```

replace table_name with your tablename . Also replace column_name with your column name